# Any way to make everything smaller on my Nokia Lumia 1520?

Tags: 8.0, lumia

Just got the new, huge, Nokia Lumia 1520 and everything is way too large.  I know the font can get smaller and still legible because in desktop mode in IE it works on some web sites, zoomed out, but it seems that in settings things can only get bigger, not smaller.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [review](http://www.theverge.com/2013/11/18/5116360/nokia-lumia-1520-review), Windows Phone 8 just scales items the OS up rather than giving you more screen real estate:

> When designing a large, high-resolution device, there are two paths to
>   take. Everything can be the same size as on smaller devices, therefore
>   displaying much more content at once. Or the interface can be scaled
>   up, displaying the same amount of content but with much larger icons,
>   fonts, and interface elements. **Microsoft chose to more or less just
>   scale the Windows Phone 8 interface up**.

Hopefully the 8.1 update will address this.

Comment: That review is a touch biased, as [Microsoft recommends that developers update their apps to be large screen aware](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/11/22/taking-advantage-of-large-screen-windows-phones.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is up to developers to adjust their apps to better take advantage of the additional real estate of larger screen devices. There is nothing the a user can do to force an app that has been scaled up to be smaller.

If you need the [text larger](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-8-tip-make-text-bigger), there are ways to make it bigger for readability.